# Windows device driver I/O request through File

Tags: windows, driver, pci

As far as I know, it seems windows sends I/O request through accessing Device File.

My understanding is that:

- Find device path
- Create a file under that device path (like $devicePath\$FileName)
- ReadFile or WriteFile to raise I/O request to that device.

In this scenario, is it allowed to create any file under target device path? Will any r/w call for all files under device will raise I/O request and send it to device driver code?

Comment: *is it allowed to create any file under target device path* - this is depend from driver implementation. many drivers ignore FileName at all. file system drivers always handle it. not any FileName is allowed and can be ignored too. *will raise I/O request and send it to device driver code* - if driver register fast i/o or normal dispatch to read/write - than yes. if not register any of this - no

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/